# Nvidia drivers for GeForce 9600 GT don't work

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, debian

I am using Lubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish).Im on a desktop.

I tried installing the driver for my GPU several ways. I tried to install them through Additional Drivers but no drivers pop up. I also tried installing them with the terminal using the following command in the download directory:

```
sudo ./(the driver that I need)
```

I have also tried the solution on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463276/installing-proprietary-nvidia-driver-for-geforce-9600-gt-on-ubuntu-14-04) but it still didn't work.

I still get screen tearing and a lot of screen ghosting. Also I have terrible FPS in games.

Im pretty sure that the drivers are the problem because i get alot of screen glitching.

The hardwere i think is not the problem because i can run all the games prefectly on windows 10.Also the game i tried playing is CS:GO.On windows it runs on 50-60 fps in a competitive match but on lubuntu it just runs at 1-9 fps in the menu and when i try to put higher graphics the textures start glitching.
Today when I tried to run CS:GO my screen started gitching so much(if i can i will attach a picture of it). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeBCW.jpg)

Comment: You've not provided any release details; Lubuntu is just a different desktop (a *flavor*) of Ubuntu Desktop and as such uses the same features as Ubuntu; though installation media can have different defaults for 20.04 & later LTS releases (*but the same options are available post-install*) but we don't know your release or starting point. You've also tagged it's a Debian/Ubuntu workflow issue yet haven't said how that relates?  Please provide release & clarify your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are out luck: NVIDIA no longer provides driver updates for that HW since 2019 (last version appears to be [340.108](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156163/)) and will very likely NOT work with the latest version of Ubuntu 22.04.

You can try older versions of Ubuntu that are still on support (like 18.04 or 20.04) and pray it works.

Otherwise you'll either have to run using nouveau in base clock mode (which as you've found out, it is very slow) or buy a newer GPU. Preferably from Linux-friendly vendors like AMD or Intel.